# Angular Can activate infinite calls

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

My auth guard is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class CheckToken implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        let url: string = state.url;
        return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

    checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        var token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');

        if(token) {
            return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Issue is that line `this.router.navigate(['/login'])` call infinite times and page break. It works fine but after updating `angular-cli` this error occur

My routes

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [CheckToken] },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }, 
{ path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },  
];
```

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer updated

Comment: As Tiep Phan already explained. If `token` is `false` you have an `endless loop.

Comment: no this is not issue..even if I simple add this.router.navigate('/login') it gives error als

Answer (score 2):

something go wrong these line

```
if(token && url=="/login"){
    return true;
}
```

if user do not login -> token = null/undefined, -> loop forever.

try this:

```
if(token || url=="/login"){
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

> basically my issue is that I want when token exists and user again hit
>   login url I want to redirect him to dashboard page

```
if(token) {
    if (url=="/login") {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

or

redirect in LoginComponent

Comment: no this is not issue..even if I simple add this.router.navigate('/login') it gives  error also

Comment: Of course, then you have an endless loop without a condition. Now you have one with a condition that always matches. There is no difference. What's the point anyway of navigating to where you already are. You should rather navigate away if there is no need to login in.

Comment: huh, let's see, if you do not login, then token is `false`, even your url is `/login`, so the block code won't execute, but this `this.router.navigate(['/login']); return false;` will. so your app redirect to `/login` again, again, and again. that it's.

Comment: can you give me suggestion then how to do this?

Comment: use || instead of &&, btw, `login route` do not need to be guard just remove it, then your conditional only `if(token) { return true; }`

Comment: then it enter endless loop

Comment: oh man, just remove guard `{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [CheckToken] }, ` to `{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}, `

Comment: basically my issue is that I want when token exists and user again hit login url I want to redirect him to dashboard page

Comment: for first case it works for 2nd not....I also update my routes in question

Comment: what did you mean about `for 2nd not.` now it loop forever with login route or another route